# ErrorBoundary not working in functional component with Suspense

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I am working with a functional component in which I implemented Lazy loading and compoent is lazy loading fine. But in a sanario while there is no component ErrorBoundary is not working  and app is breaking with no fallback UI/msg.
My code is

```
export const SiteContent = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  let LazyLoadedComponent = null;
  if (selectedOption?.component) {
    LazyLoadedComponent = React.lazy(
      () =>
        import(
          `./components/${selectedOption.option.value}/${selectedOption.option.value}`
        )
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading....</div>}>
          {selectedOption?.component && LazyLoadedComponent && (
            <LazyLoadedComponent />
          )}
        </Suspense>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </>
  );
};
```

ErrorBoundary code is

```
import React from "react";
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Comment: Can you also include your `ErrorBoundary`'s code?

Comment: Are you able to see the fallback UI after closing React's error overlay?

Comment: No, I can`t see.

Comment: Try setting your `hasError` state to `true` in the `componentDidCatch` method and let me know if that works.

Comment: Put it in answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your `hasError` state to `true` in the `componentDidCatch` method.

```
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
  this.setState({ hasError: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `hasError` state to `true` for the fallback UI to be shown.

Change your `ErrorBoundary`'s `componentDidCatch` to :

```js
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    this.setState({ hasError: true});
  }
```